# Heroku 409 error when Python Dash app calls API

Tags: python, api, heroku, server, plotly-dash

starting process with command from procfile works.

then as soon as it starts reading the python file, and pulling data from an API, we get

```
[2020-03-23 17:48:55 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

Which traces down to

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 409: Conflict
```

And then

```
[2020-03-23 17:48:55 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
```

Before it looks like its successfully calling the API on a second attempt and then ultimately

```
[2020-03-23 17:49:03 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
[2020-03-23 17:49:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-03-23 17:49:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

And it crashes, exiting with status 3.

How do I solve this 409 error? Is there some environment variable or something that has to be set in the python app before deploying to Heroku? The app works locally (i.e. API calls work), just when trying to put on a server do I encounter this.

Comment: which api are you calling? It's possible you need to authenticate with SSH certification or whitelist an IP address.

Comment: trading economics